# Diffusion Fick's 1st law for non-isothermal ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, diffusion

I have some doubts regarding diffusion. Let's imagine two chambers, with infinite volume, connected by a capillary. Both chambers are filled with the same gas, but at different temperatures, thus creating a change in concentration. Does that cause a diffusive flux between them?

Thank you in advance!
Best regards,
Javi

Comment: What do you think is happening within the capillary as a function of time (assuming the pressures in the chambers are equal)?

Comment: In this case, it is a thought experiment, both chambers would remain constant and I'm imagining the capillary as just an infinitesimal hole connecting them. I am curious whether we should consider some diffusive flux caused by the change in total density.
I see you are a Chemical Engineer, in particular I am curious whether we should consider formulation for diffusive flux a or b in non isothermal reactors/catalysts:
a/ ji = D·∇ci = D·∇(p/(RT)·yi)
b/ ji = D·p/(RT) ∇yi

Comment: In the case of ideal gases, the driving force for diffusion is partial pressure, not concentration.  But, in any event, you can't have mass diffusion without having different chemical species (other than radioactively tagged versions of the same species).  In the case of the capillary in your experiment, there would be heat conduction but, of course, no diffusion.  Any transfer of gas would be considered to be by bulk movement.